# referencing this inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, this

Given the code (a lot of it stripped out)

```
// A data set
$.DataArea = function() {

    // Default options
    $.extend(this, {
        'class': "DataSet",
        'bars': new Array(),
        'container': null,
        'containerId': null,
        'gridsize': 20,
        'width': 400,
        'height': 400,
        'currentSelectedBar': 0
    });

    // Add a bar to this object
    this.addBar = function(startDate, endDate, label, styleID) {

        // When the bar is clicked
        $('#' + barID).click(function() {

            alert($(this).currentSelectedBar);
            if (this.currentSelectedBar != undefined)
                $('#' + this.currentSelectedBar).fadeIn("slow");

            this.currentSelectedBar = barID;
                $('#' + barID).fadeTo("slow", 0.5);

        });
    }
```

When I `alert($(this).currentSelectedBar);` it always comes out as undefined, it's not setting the value properly.  Any ideas why this might be?

The idea is when you click on a bar, it fades it out, and when you click another the last bar to fade out fades in as well.

Comment: I think you have more than just this one problem. As @Robert correctly pointed in his comment to my (now deleted) answer, `this` refers to the DOM element you bind the event handler to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are calling `addBar` on an instance of `DataArea`, your code should be:

```
// Add a bar to this object
this.addBar = function(startDate, endDate, label, styleID) {
    var self = this;
    // When the bar is clicked
    $('#' + barID).click(function() {

        alert(self.currentSelectedBar);
        if (self.currentSelectedBar != undefined)
            $('#' + self.currentSelectedBar).fadeIn("slow");

        self.currentSelectedBar = this.id;
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
    });
}
```

Inside the `click` handler, `this` will refer to the DOM element `'#' + barID`. But the properties are assigned to some other element and not that DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` in your callback function refers to the element that rises the event : in that case `$('#' + barID)`.
I guess you want to access the `this` that you extended. In that case, you should write something like that :

```
this.addBar = function(startDate, endDate, label, styleID) {
    var self = this

    // When the bar is clicked
    $('#' + barID).click(function() {

        alert($(self).currentSelectedBar);
        if (self.currentSelectedBar != undefined)
            $('#' + self.currentSelectedBar).fadeIn("slow");

        self.currentSelectedBar = barID;
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.5);

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var that = this;
    $('#' + barID).click(function() {

        alert(that.currentSelectedBar);
        if (that.currentSelectedBar != undefined)
            $('#' + this.currentSelectedBar).fadeIn("slow");

        that.currentSelectedBar = barID;
            $('#' + barID).fadeTo("slow", 0.5);

    });
```

Cache the value of `this` outside the click function. inside the click function, the context `this` is the DOM node that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're having an issue with the behavior of jQuery.

`$('#' + barID).click(function() {` remaps the definition of `this`, but having attempted to add attributes to it previously will have no effect because the definition of `this` has been overwritten.

As mentioned by recmashak you can put the original `this` into a variable and then use it when you do your alert

Comment: jQuery has nothing to do with it. It's basic Javascript scoping rules.

Comment: I don't think what I said was necessarily wrong.  It was a conscious decision for the jQuery developers to remap `this` inside of event handlers.  Prototype doesn't do that (you call `event.element()` instead).  Without that remapping `this`, it would have referred to the `this.addBar` object, which is JavaScript scoping rules (and still not the same as the original `this` that was extended)